# Series converging almost everywhere.

Tags: measure-theory

Any help with the following would be great.

Prove that if $(X,F,u)$ is a measure space and $\{f_k\}$ is a sequence of functions on $X$ such that $\sum \int \vert f_k \vert du < \infty$ then there is a null set $A \in F$ such that the series $\sum f_k$ converges for every $x \in X\setminus A$ .

Comment: See e.g. Richard M. Dudley's book *Real Analysis and Probability* (or any other similar) the pages where he proves completeness of the $L^p$ spaces (if I recall correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Under your stated hypothesis The Beppo Levi theorem implies $\displaystyle \int_X \sum |f_k| \, d\mu < \infty$. It is a standard result (using e.g. the Chebyshev inequality) that if an integral is finite, the integral is finite almost everywhere. A series of positive terms converges if and only if its sum is finite, so that $$\sum_k |f_k| < \infty \mathrm{\ a.e.} \implies  \sum_k |f_k| \mathrm{\  converges\ a.e.}$$ The series of the $\{f_k\}$ converges whenever the series of the $\{|f_k|\}$ does.